# Not able to start PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, postgresql-9.2

Have a CentOS7 Linux machine running (not managed by me; have limited rights to/in it).

Have a request to set PostgreSQL up in it.

Just installed PostgreSQL from the CentOS repository:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
```

All good with it.

Then did initialization of the database:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
```

All good with it.

But then the start:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Fails:

```
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I do not have access to systemd-journal so nothing tod with "journalctl -xe", but then the:

```
systemctl status postgresql.service
```

returns:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-04-24 16:41:04 EEST; 33s ago
  Process: 30690 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30684 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

```
postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here? Hot to continue with that?

Comment: Start it with `pg_ctl start` as operating system user `postgres` and look at the error messages.

Comment: I am not able to see initdb in your question, Have you done it?
/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/postgresql92-setup initdb
 After that enable service and start service using systemctl enable postgresql-9.2 and 
systemctl start postgresql-9.2

Comment: @AmjadShahzad Oh sorry, have added the install part twice, instead of the init. So the init part was done like this:
`sudo postgresql-setup initdb`
And all good with that one.
Now did also the enable:
`sudo systemctl enable postgresql`
all good with that one.
But then the start fails the same:
`sudo systemctl start postgresql
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your reply. Did now `sudo -u postgres -i` and then 'pg_ctl start' . Got then `FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server. DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.2.24.`. How is that logical? Did a fresh installation, so how they can be incompatible? Any hints to get past that?

Comment: Do you also have PG9.3 installed on your Machine? what you have in your `/var/lib/pgsql/` also what you get when you do `echo $PGDATA`

Comment: Also on a side note, If you don't have any limitation of using the PG9.2(which is not in active development anymore) then it is better to install the latest version of Postgres. i.e PG12

Comment: @AmjadShahzad thanks for your help. `echo $PGDATA` returns `/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data` and ls in `/var/lib/pgsql/` returns `9.3  backups  data  initdb.log` So no 9.2. but the `postgres --version` returns `postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24`. Any ideas how this can be? If I just installed it from CentOS repository then why do i have two different versions now going around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `echo $PGDATA` shows you have PG9.3 as well. Which means that 9.2 service will not start because the port 5432 might be already occupied by postgres 9.3 
Do the following

```
ps- ef | grep postgres
```

And get the postgres process id and kill all postgres processes.

Remove the 9.3 data directory using

```
rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/9.3
```

Go to `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` and run the initdb using below command

```
./postgresql92-setup initdb
```

After that start the postgresql-9.2 service using

```
systemctl start postgresql-9.2.service
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be both PostgreSQL 9.2 and 9.3 installed on your machine. Deinstall them both and install version 12 from the PostgreSQL site. Remove the data directory and create a new one with the v12 installation. Then try again.